# How does this follow from Ito's formula?

Tags: itos-lemma

Let $S_t$ be a geometric brownian motion and let $M_t = \sup_{0 \le u \le t} S_t$ be the maximum process.

Define $X_t = \frac{M_t}{S_t}$.

A book I am reading states the following:

[image]

**How does this follow from Ito's formula?** Where does the indicator function come from?

Comment: Is the only issue you have with the indicator function? I am pretty sure that it is just there for clarity. So basically it is showing that unless $X_s = 1$ that $dM_s = 0$. This is since only when the spot is equal to the running max, does $dM_s$ have a nonzero value, since the max updates to the spot whenever the spot is greater than the previous max value.

Comment: Also please indicate the book this is from or more details on the dynamics of $S$